# Invoke custom function that display a form

Tags: vtiger

I need to use multiple custom function on my VTiger. Currently i am successfully create a custom function that are passing a data from vtiger to other system whenever project are saved.

Now i need to create another custom function that prompt a form to the user to fill in. The data fill by the user would be saved on the database.

Is there anyway to call the custom function that can display a form a user to fill in and then processing the form. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to invoke a form from vtiger custom function.